# How to make events permanent in fullcalendar

Tags: php, javascript, json, calendar, fullcalendar

How can I make the event changes in [FULLCALENDAR](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) permanent?

I can only change the events when editing the code, but if i edit it on my browser like this example here [SELECTABLE](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/demos/selectable.html) then refresh all the edits I've made disappears, how can I make this changes permanent ? what methods can be done so that the changes I make are permanent, when i edit it from my website?

Answer (score 0):

When you (re)render the event you should set the option stick to true.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/
That will persist the event client side. 
If you want the events laters you should save them to db.